# Website's Mobile Version Behaves Different From Desktop Version

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, socialengine

In terms of UI, a website's mobile version obviously is different from Desktop mode, and that is fine. However, my Social Engine website seems to behave different from desktop version when making purchase from store. The website uses Social Engine Addons' Marketplace and Mobile/Tablet plugins. I have added the payment gateway code inside `./application/libraries/Engine/Payment/Gateway/Mygateway.php`, the `processTransaction()` method in the Engine_Payment_Gateway class. It gets some basic product info like price and order id and sends them along with authentication info to the gateway SOAP service. This works fine in Desktop mode, but when placing an order in mobile view, this gateway is not loaded. Rather, when the user confirms the order, a page is shown with order info, rather than being redirected to the payment page. 
Is there a way I can inspect where the site sends requests or which php file is loaded in mobile mode purchase using Chrome? Or does anyone how I can get around this issue in mobile version?

Comment: I think you should ask third-party developers (SocialEngineAddons) regarding inappropriate work of their marketplace in mobile mode.

Comment: Different module is used for mobile version.